# Why is this proof not 100% correct? (Eisenstein Criterion)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I solved a question in an exam and I would like to know why do you think I didn't get 100% of this question (they gave me 18/20 points). The question is to state and prove the Eisenstein criterion. I solved in the following manner:

**Eisenstein criterion**

Let $p(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0\in \mathbb Z[X]$. If there exist a prime number $p$ such that $p\nmid a_n,p\mid a_i$ for $i=0,\ldots n-1$ and $p^2\nmid a_0$, then $p(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

*Proof*

Suppose $p(X)$ holds the conditions of the theorem and $p(X)=g(X)h(X)$ with $g(X),h(X)\in \mathbb Z[X], g(X)=b_mX^m+\ldots+b_0$ and $h(X)=c_tX^t+\ldots+c_0$ and $m+t=n$. Since $p\nmid a_n$ and $p|a_i$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, there exist $a'\in \mathbb Z_p$ such that $p(X)=a'X^n$ in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$. Since $p(X)=g(X)h(X)$, it follows $g(X)=b'X^m$ and $h(X)=c'X^t$ in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$. Therefore $p^2|b_0c_0$, contradiction because $p^2\nmid a_0$.

Comment: Points off without an explanation?  Lame.

Comment: @KajHansen I'm sorry. I didn't follow you.

Comment: I'm just lamenting the fact that you got points off on a test without an explanation from (presumably) your professor.  Seems like common courtesy, lol.  Anyways, it might be because you want to also include $m, t > 1$.  Otherwise, you can just factor out a constant.

Comment: @KajHansen Yes, so sad. He isn't my professor. Otherwise I could ask him personally why he didn't give me 100% of the question.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write $m, t \geq 1$ above.

Comment: @KajHansen do you think I should have written $m,t>1$ in the beginning of the proof?

Comment: @KajHansen: Why do you want to include $m, t\geq 1$ ? Sometimes a polynomial will be reducible but still not a product of two smaller-degree polynomials.

Comment: Also, to be somewhat pedantic, the criterion needs an $n \geq 1$ requirement. Degree-$0$ polynomials can be reducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are points were docked for sloppy (or not-perfect) formulation. Here is a bunch of nitpicks.

- You use the same symbol, $p$, for the polynomial and the prime.
- The degree of $p$ should be at least $1$, i.e. $n \geq 1$.
- "Suppose $p(X)$ holds the conditions of the theorem" sounds weird to me.
- It's not immediately clear what is meant exactly by "Suppose $p(x)$ holds the conditions of the theorem". Being very strict, I would interpret it as "Suppose there exists a prime $p$ satisfying the conditions as in the theorem", but then you haven't formally picked such a $p$.
- Formally, is your approach to assume that $p(X)$ is reducible and then derive a contradiction, or is your approach to write $p(X)$ as a product $g(X)h(X)$ and deduce that one of $g(X)$, $h(X)$ is a unit? That's not immediately clear at the point that you introduce $g(X)$ and $h(X)$.
- $a'$ is just (the residue class of) $a_n$; why the "exists $a'$" then?
- Same for $b'$ and $a'$.
- The proof is more elegant if you reduce modulo $p$ right at the start without bothering to give names to the coefficients of $g(X)$ and $h(X)$.
- You could be more explicit about why $p^2 \mid b_0 c_0$ and about the fact that $b_0 c_0 = a_0$.

Now, is this worth deducing $10$% of the points available? I don't know, but there is a case to be made for "the proof is not 100% perfect and therefore it is not worth 100% of points".

Comment: $m,t>1$ is unnecessary (and cannot be ensured). But $n\geq 0$ is important.

Answer (score 0):

There are two pays to prove Eisenstein's Criterion. One method is to writing out $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ and prove that either $m=n$ or $t=n$. This method is a bit tedious. Second method is to start by taking modulo $p$. This method is about 1 line long. It seems you used a mixture of these two. Your solution is more or less correct but a bit difficult to read. I feel like the grader just skimmed through it, had trouble understanding, and decided to give you 8/10 and not bother fully understanding.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this proof "1 line long"? do you know exactly where is my mistake? Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/eisenstein.html.

It's the first proof on top. You can cut out a lot of the words to make it 1 line. This is essentially what you did half way through.